# How define a unique constrain using JPA nosql (eclipselink) and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, jpa, nosql, eclipselink, jpa-2.2

I trying to define a Nosql entity using org.eclipse.persistence.nosql libraries but I'm not able to define a unique constraint.

So, until now I've been looking for something like the following SQL syntax but for the NOSql annotation.
`@Entity @Table(name="TDWC_DATASOURCE", uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"name", "userId"}))`

Is there any param/option to have a constraint also in nosql db? Is there any alternative?
Thanks in advance
Andrea

Comment: Not something standard in noSQL (https://www.infoworld.com/article/3240644/what-is-nosql-databases-for-a-cloud-scale-future.html#:~:text=With%20NoSQL%2C%20imposing%20constraints%20involves,does%20not%20typically%20support%20that. ) and it isn't supported in EclipseLInk classes that I've seen. If you find a way to do it though, it should be could be add to the mongoDB platform class within eclipseLink (latest mongoDb might have support https://www.educba.com/mongodb-unique/ )